# Show that $H$ is transitive on the set $G$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Let $G$ be a group and let a be a fixed element of $G$.

The map $\lambda_{a}: G \to G$, given by $\lambda_{a}(g) = ag$ for all $g \in G$, is a permutation of the set $G$.

Note $H = \{\lambda_{a} \mid a \in G\}$ is a subgroup of $S_{G},$ the group of all permutations of $G$.

The answer is as follows: We must show that for each $a, b \in G$ there exists some $λ_{c} \in H$ such that $λ_{c}(a) = b$. We need only choose $c$ such that $ca=b$, that is we take $c=ba^{-1}$.

Can someone please explain this. I don't know where they took the $c$ from and why they just let $ca=b$.

Answer (score 1):

For $H$ to be transitive on the set $G$, this means that the group orbit of $H$ on an element of $G$ is all of $G$. That is, for some element $a \in G$, there is a permutation of $G$ in $H$ (recall the elements of $H$ are special permutations of $G$) that takes $a$ to $b$ for any $b \in G$. Hence, we must demonstrate the existence of a map $\lambda_{c} \in H$ such that $\lambda_{c}(a) = ca = b$ for any $b \in G$.

Since this map is just left multiplication by the element $c$, this amounts to finding a $c \in G$ such that $ca = b$. By right multiplying both sides by $a^{-1}$, we obtain $c = ba^{-1} \in G$, so that

$$\lambda_{c}(a) = ba^{-1}a = b$$ 
as desired.